# Nested Transformation with Fractal, Dingo API, Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, dingo-api

I'm trying to transform a collection of **tickets** with the following code

```
public function transform(Ticket $ticket) {
    return [
        'id' => $ticket->id,
        'title' => $ticket->title,
        'status' => $this->transformerMessage($ticket->status),
        'interactions' => 
              $this->collection(
                   $ticket->interactions,
                   new InteractionTransformer(),
                   'interactions'
              )
    ];
}
```

But the **interactions** result is always empty. Here is an example of output I'm getting:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Earum repudiandae corporis sapiente at odit itaque ratione.",
      "status": "Open",
      "interactions": {}
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Odit impedit vitae quo sit molestiae eius.",
      "status": "Open",
      "interactions": {}
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Fuga cum corrupti ut.",
      "status": "Open",
      "interactions": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

if I try to **die and dump** the `$ticket->interactions` variable, I get a Collection of 5 items (which proves the variable isn't empty).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. Callback referencing the dingo transform:

```
public function transform(Ticket $ticket) {
    $output = $ticket->interactions;
    $trans = new InteractionTransformer();
    return [
        'id' => $ticket->id,
        'title' => $ticket->title,
        'status' => $this->transformerMessage($ticket->status),
        'interactions' => 
              $ticket->interactions->transform(
                 function($i) use ($trans) {
                    return $trans->transform($i);
                 }
              )
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $this in your collection call is referring to the transformer which inherits from TransformerAbstract which creates a Collection from a Resource type.

Try adding ->getData() to the end to pull the REAL collection from the Dingo Resource Collection.

```
public function transform(Ticket $ticket) {
    return [
        'id' => $ticket->id,
        'title' => $ticket->title,
        'status' => $this->transformerMessage($ticket->status),
        'interactions' => 
              $this->collection(
                   $ticket->interactions,
                   new InteractionTransformer(),
                   'interactions'
              )->getData()
    ];
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it technically works, but the data pulled didn't pass through the `transform`method of the `InteractionTransformer()`

Comment: Ooops.  You're right.  Missed that.  I added an alternative answer above.